# How do I get into a masters course in pure mathematics?

Tags: soft-question, education

My question is as stated in the title and to elaborate more:

I would like to know if there are any standardized international exams to enter a masters course in pure mathematics (besides GRE Math) and avail a scholarship simultaneously? (I'm a graduate in Automotive engineering).

I have completed 5 courses related to engineering mathematics during my tenure as an engineer.

I've been prepping only on math (topology, differential geometry, advanced calculus, real analysis etc.) for the past 6 months and am almost ready for an entrance exam.

Can anyone offer me alternate options or solutions on how to go about this?

Sorry for a non-mathematical query, this is one of very few places I can seek help.

Comment: Now that [Academia StackExchange](http://academia.stackexchange.com) is online, perhaps this is more appropriate there? However, it's probably true that there are more people here are qualified to answer this question.

Comment: Previously posted at http://mathoverflow.net/questions/92440/how-do-i-get-into-a-masters-course-in-pure-mathematics-closed
Also posted at http://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/922/how-do-i-get-into-a-masters-course-in-pure-mathematics

Comment: http://www.daad.de/stipendien/en/index.en.html?

Comment: I guess it will be hard to come into a math master's without a serious math background. I guess it will be easier to join a Bachelor's programme, and then with your background and preparation you will be able to complete it faster than usual? For example you can study the Bachelor's at ETH Zurich when you speak German and pass the entrance exam.

Answer (score 2):

I can speak only for the United States.

There is an exam (the GRE) but it is not the most important part of your application.

In the US, generally you apply to Ph.D. programs, as those come with funding more often. You can typically leave after two years with a master's degree if you like.

Recommendation letters and transcripts are the most important. Since your degree is not in math, yours are not likely to be looked at favorably by admissions committees (unfortunately). Also, self-study is great, but it doesn't leave you a good way of proving what you know.

If at all possible, I recommend taking a couple of upper level (grad-level if possible) math courses at a well-known university in your country. Probably you won't do this as a degree student, and you will have to pay for them, but if there is a way around it then I'm afraid I don't know it.

An alternative, in case that won't work, is to travel to a well-known university at least once and try to meet with professors who may be willing to speak up on your behalf. As a way of getting your foot in the door, you might answer some math questions on Math.SE or MathOverflow. This will confirm for people that your interest and ability are genuine. This won't get you into grad programs by itself, but it might be enough to get the attention of people who might eventually be willing to recommend you.